# How to reload the CSS file after orientation change (phone)?

Tags: css, mobile, screen-orientation

For the gallery on my website I use media queries to readjust the image sizes depending on the screen width (I use the folio theme by galleria) and the image size is supposed to change when you tilt your phone - but that only happens after you reload it manually. (Adding orientation landscape or portrait doesn't do anything).

So basically, I want to avoid reloading the whole page because it involves reloading the images - the information is in the CSS file, can I reload that file individually?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Use e.g. [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and catch `orientationchange` event.

```
  $(window).bind('orientationchange', function(e) {
    if(e.orientation === 'landscape'){
        //edit you CSS
        // or reload image
    }else{
        // roll back
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I bind this to an if/else statement? Basically I need an exception to the reloading when the image is in fullscreen (because when it reloads in fullscreen, you exit fullscreen). Or is there something like an ignore function I could use? Sorry I'm new to this!

Answer (score 0):

All recent smartphone and tablet browsers definitely support media queries based on orientation, see [article here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/). It is mentioned there that it is supported from iOS 4.0 upwards. If you scroll down the **Bonus: iPhone support** section it also provides a workaround for phones that are quirky about triggering automatically.

If you specify the media query as part of the CSS include it shouldn't be loaded until it becomes applicable, automatically solving your problem.

If you still run into platforms that have problems, you can use the [Javascript onOrientationChange event](http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change) as a fallback, using for example [Mootools Utility/Asset](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Utilities/Assets) to load images and stylesheets at runtime, or its jQuery counterpart.